# Problems getting jobs and education on Linkedin with Django (Python Social Auth)

Tags: django, linkedin-api, python-social-auth, linkedin-jsapi

I'm trying to get the linkedin profile, as complete as possible. The problem is that LinkedIn does not give me the "r_fullprofile" option whereby, "educations" I get them as "null" and "positions" only returns me the current jobs

The only permissions Linkedin offers me, are:

- r_basicprofile
- r_emailaddress
- rw_company_admin
- w_share

How I can get all the information before returning r_fullprofile me?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to `r_fullprofile` requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn.

**These profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for the [Apply with LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) use case.**

**Member profile fields**

The following selection of profile fields are available to all LinkedIn developers:

1. Basic Profile Fields
2. Location Fields
3. Position Fields

**Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers:**

The following selection of profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for the Apply with LinkedIn use case:

1. Full Profile Fields
2. Contact Info Fields
3. Company Fields
4. Publication Fields
5. Patent Fields
6. Language Fields
7. Skill Fields
8. Certification Fields
9. Course Fields
10. Education Fields
11. Volunteer Fields

**Check out this [linkedin page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields) for more details on which fields are available to all the developers and which are not.**